# Avoid fireworks/firecrackers in Taiwan

Tags: safety, health, local-customs, taiwan

I have ligyrophobia (the fear of loud sounds). It is possible for me to tolerate things like balloons and thunders, but fireworks/firecrackers will send me into a panic attack.

I will be travelling to Taiwan in December. According to my understanding, setting off fireworks/firecrackers are quite common in Taiwan, especially at certain places (e.g. temples) and during festive celebrations.

My question is, where should I avoid visiting if I want to avoid any chance of encountering fireworks/firecrackers? And also what time of the year should I expect frequent fireworks/firecrackers to be set off?

Comment: +1 for a great question. Starred as favourite and looking forward to some great answers.

Answer (score 8):

TL;DR: **You're probably fine**.

The big occasion for firecrackers in Taiwan (and the rest of the Chinese world) is **Chinese (Lunar) New Year**, which is traditionally celebrated at the stroke of midnight by, you guessed it, *lots* of deafeningly loud firecrackers.  However, lunar new year is well after the Gregorian one and next falls on February 8, 2016, so you'll easily avoid this.

The other firecracker event Taiwan is famous for is the Yanshui Beehive Fireworks Festival (鹽水蜂炮), which is [certifiably insane](http://digg.com/video/firecracker-battle-taiwan-dont-breathe-that-in) -- but is also linked to Chinese New Year and celebrated at the same time.  What's more, this is a specialty of Yanshui in Tainan to the south, the rest of the island celebrates more sedately with (quiet, non-exploding) lanterns.

And of course the Western New Year (Jan 1) is celebrated with a fireworks display centered on the Taipei 101 building.

Comment: I'm not sure whether that is the case in Taiwan, too, but at least in parts of mainland China, another thing the OP should avoid and that is not bound to specific dates is getting married.

Comment: How about national or local temple celebration such as [this](https://www.sinica.edu.tw/tit/festivals/0497_Matsu.html)? And also what are the chances of people setting off fireworks/firecrackers in a park or rural areas on a non-festive day?